# Переключение между фрагментами с Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-navigation-drawer, navigation, android-navigation-view

Поленился и добавил меню из стандартного шаблона, как оказалось зря ибо это отняло у меня времени в сотни раз больше.
Мне нужно из фрагмента Главная переключаться между item в боковом меню.
Вот весь код NavigationDrawer

```js
package esport.inyourlife.insport;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import esport.inyourlife.insport.Sign.SignIn;
import esport.inyourlife.insport.ui.home.HomeFragment;

public class HomeNav extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
   // private TextView uMail;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private TextView uMail, uName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_nav);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Позже уберу эту штуку, при оптимизаций приложений", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
       /* uMail.findViewById(R.id.uMail);
        uName.findViewById(R.id.uName);
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null)
        {
            uMail.setText(user.getEmail());
            if (!user.getDisplayName().equals(null))
            {
                uName.setText(user.getDisplayName());
            }
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_nav, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){
            case R.id.signout :
            mAuth.signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoadFrame.class));
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
    public void Profile(View v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    // public void SignOut(View view) { mAuth.signOut(); }

}
```

и не понятно где тут код выбора item, а где тут привязывать код к компонентам. xml если понадобиться могу скинуть, дело в том что оно создало 3-4 xml фрагментов и все они только для меню.
MainDrawer.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
            android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
            android:title="@string/menu_slideshow" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

HomeNav.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MobileNavigation.xml :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="esport.inyourlife.insport.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:name="esport.inyourlife.insport.ui.gallery.TournamentFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_gallery"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_tournament" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_gallery_to_showTurnirs"
            app:destination="@id/showTurnirs" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:name="esport.inyourlife.insport.ui.slideshow.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_slideshow"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_slideshow_to_friends2"
            app:destination="@id/friends2" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_slideshow_to_profileEdit"
            app:destination="@id/profileEdit" />
    </fragment>
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/friends2"
        android:name="esport.inyourlife.insport.Profile.Friends"
        android:label="activity_friends"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_friends" />
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/profileEdit"
        android:name="esport.inyourlife.insport.Profile.ProfileEdit"
        android:label="activity_profile_edit"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_profile_edit" />
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/showTurnirs"
        android:name="esport.inyourlife.insport.ShowTurnirs"
        android:label="ShowTurnirs" />
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To navigate from current fragment to next fragment, use this code in your current fragment:

```
Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.xml_button);
button.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.nextFragment, null));
```

To navigate with a transition animation, set the id of the fragment you want to navigate to (nextFragment), to the id of the action containing the fragment transition.

```
Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.xml_button);
button.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_currentFragment_to_nextFragment, null));
```

If you already have an onClickListener set for the button, place this inside it instead:

```
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.nextFragment);
```

//Спасибо @Andrew из англоязычного stackoverflow